# cakephp restrict action depending on user status

Tags: cakephp, authorization, cakephp-3.2

I'm using CakePHP 3.2 to develop seller panel.

There is `sellers` table to store all details and credentials and there is a column `status` on integer type.

`status` column is used to mark seller as approved or not like this

```
0 = Registered not approved
1 = Approved
2 = Canceled
```

There is `sell` action in `ProductsController.php`.

I want to allow this action to only seller whose status is 1. And print message as per status id if user is not approved like

```
1 : Sorry! Your account is not verified yet.
2 : Sorry! Your account has been canceled. Contact Admin.
```

This is what I'm doing to prevent `sell` action. I have added following code in `beforeFilter()` of `ProductsController.php`

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);

        if ($this->Auth->user('status') != 1) {
            $this->Auth->deny(['sell']);
        }
    }
```

But this is not working and `sell` action is still accessible to all sellers.

Comment: Try `$this->Auth->user()['status']`

Comment: not working @JacekBBudzyñski

Comment: it should be working - can you debug $this->Auth->user() ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your *Auth* configuration `'checkAuthIn'` on `initialize()` to  `'Controller.initialize'` (default `'Controller.startup'`):

```
$this->Auth->config('checkAuthIn', 'Controller.initialize');
```

To use `$this->Auth->user()` in `beforeFilter()` as described in [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#deciding-when-to-run-authentication).